# Permiso denegado abriendo archivo R desde Linux bash como subsistema de win 10

Tags: linux, r, bash

Estoy intentando abrir un script en R utilizando Linux bash como subsistema de Win 10.

El archivo se encuentra aquí:

```
/mnt/c/Users/xxxx/collect.R
```

La salida de bash es:

```
Fatal error: cannot open file '/mnt/c/Users/xxxx/collect.R' permission denied.
```

El archivo de R contiene un shebang en la primera línea que es así:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript.exe
```

Previamente me he encargado de exportar el PATH desde windows para que sea ejecutable en bash. Creo que está todo correcto.

He intentado todo tipo de comandos, incluyendo sudo chmod, chmod u+x, chmod 644 etc...

Al comprobar cuáles son los permisos del archivo obtengo esto:

```
-rwxrwxrwx      MYUSERNAME DATE     /mnt/c/Users/xxxx/collect.R
```

**Edición 1 (25/5/2020)**

Añado un [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61988875/setting-up-directories-for-cron-job-using-linux-bash-shell-to-collect-data-using?noredirect=1#comment109671702_61988875) a la evolución de mi pregunta en la plataforma en inglés por si ayuda a resolver el problema:

Aprecio mucho la ayuda porque esto se me está atravesando.

Comment: Muy probablemente necesites permisos de root

Comment: ¿Cómo se hace esto? Soy seminuevo en Linux

Comment: el tema es que hay acciones que solamente puede usar el usuario root, o un usuario normal con permisos de `sudo`. Por tanto, antes de nada deberías ver si este comando te funciona tal cual o si solamente te funciona con algún usuario determinado (o usando `sudo`).

Comment: he venido utilizando sudo y parece que funciona con mi usuario (e.g john) actual en bash. Debería hacer algo así? `$ grep john /etc/passwd
john:x:0:0::/home/john:/bin/sh?` o así `$ sudo usermod -a -G root john` para dar permisos a este usuario?

Comment: debes configurarlo con el comando `visudo`. Allí puedes añadir una línea del tipo `myusername ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/my/program`, en este caso, `john ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /ruta/al/fichero/con/el/mnt`

Comment: He añadido esta línea y desafortunadamente la denegación persiste

Comment: Entiendo que todo viene de [tu pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/358827/83). Lo suyo sería tener un script que hiciera todos estos pasos. Es decir, añade un script.sh y ponle `/mnt/c/Users/xxxx/collect.R` así como `cd /mnt/c/Users/XXXX/Documents/Twitter; Rscript collect.R`. Después, coges la ruta del script que has creado y es la que pones en el sudoers

Comment: Permission denied al abrir script.sh, lamentablemente. Para añadir permisos entro en el panel con el comando `sudo visudo` y después añado el path que lleva al archivo en cuestión `john ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /mnt/c/Users/xxxx` debajo de donde dice #User privilege specification y salvo los cambios. Después intento ejecutar el archivo script.sh en el directorio correspondiente y la salida es permission denied

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108447/discussion-between-pyring-and-fedorqui-so-deja-de-danar).